# Would a raspberry Pi be able to read and save 6 RTSP streams

Tags: linux, debian, ffmpeg, raspberry-pi, .net-framework

I have a PC reading 6 RTSP streams and saving them to a hard drive using a .NET Core C# app which calls FFmpeg. This uses hardly any CPU on the PC and runs well.

I was wondering would a raspberry pi be up to the task of doing this with a USB hard drive?

Each camera is returning 3.2 Mb/s network traffic, and writing 0.4 MB/s to the drive as per task manager.

I would have a couple of choices, and would be open to either,

1. Get .NET core working on the pi, and run the app as it currently stands
2. Abandon the .NET core app, and write something that works natively in linux to call ffmpeg (not sure what this would look like, but python or some other script)
3. Use windows IoT core, but I am not sure whether FFmpeg would work in this circumstance?

All my .NET core app does is this,

1. Start ffmpeg to record 1 stream and stop after 15 minutes
2. Start a new recording after 14 minutes and 30 seconds (to create an overlap)
3. Start ffmpeg earlier than that if at any point it gets disconnected or stops

I'm not too worried about the details at the moment. Just whether the pi would from a performance perspective handle running 6 instances of ffmpeg to save the RTSP stream.

No re-encoding is required. It's a straight copy.

At this point I would be looking at the Raspberry Pi 3, but would consider waiting for the Pi 4 if the chances of it working are better.

Comment: The 4 should. The 3 may not have the bandwidth over the USB bus

Comment: I view it in task manager on my PC. Each camera is 3 megabits per second. What bandwidth are you talking about? Ethernet bandwidth?

Comment: USB bandwidth. On the raspberry pi 3 the Ethernet controller is attached to the USB bus. So you need to move each stream over the bus twice. (Ethernet + HDD).

Comment: Pi 4 then would have a separate bus for each?

Comment: The 4 has a separate USB2, USB3 and Ethernet. From an IO perspective, is 10 times better.

Comment: At least measure the bandwidth for your 6 RTSP streams so you can do a back-of-the-envelope calculation. "RTSP" ist just the transport protocol, it doesn't say anything about how much data is transmitted how fast. Bottlenecks will be network and disk access via USB, not CPU (unless you want to the RaspPi to do format conversion as well).

Comment: I did measure. Each camera is 3.2 Mb/s typically, that is total network as measured, nothing to do with RTSP protocol or camera config. No conversion, just straight through writing to drive. Each camera is 0.4 MB/s to the drive I can see as per my measurements. I would consider those measurements to be low, aren't they? That would be 19.2 Mb/s network, and 2.4 MB/s disk. What would you realistically expect from a Pi 3? I could wait for a Pi 4, but they are not available in NZ yet.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately I haven't answered this question. What I did do is re purpose a dual core pentium machine and install the linux distribution, KDE Neon.

I have a bunch of dotnet core code to record my cameras, and I'm happy to report that FFMpeg with my dotnet core code works very well on KDE Neon with very little modification. KDE Neon is rock solid based on it being built on LTS Ubuntu.

RTSP is a mixed bag, and some cheaper cameras giving mixed results. But this setup with FFMpeg works well.

I will look for something else to do with my Raspberry Pi.